# Mapping into table from socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, object

I'm relatively new to React - I have a backend NodeJs code reading from a file in a loop to emit data line by line to React on my frontend and I am receiving it Object by Object in this way:

```
class Logs extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    data: {}
  };
}

  componentDidMount() {
    socket.emit('initialize');
    socket.on('msg', res => {
      this.setState({data: res.msg});
    })
  }
```

Sample JSON

```
{
  'command': {
    pitch: '2',
    roll: '2',
    yaw: '56',
  }
}
```

I am having trouble mapping these data into two column in a table, this is my code so far:

```
renderTableData() {
    return  Object.values(this.state.data).map((item, i) => {
      const {pitch, roll, yaw} = item;
      return (
        <tr key={i}>
          <td>{Object.keys(this.state.data)}</td>
          <td>Pitch: {pitch},
              roll: {roll},
              Yaw: {yaw},
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
  }
```

However, it only displays the last JSON object data into the table, is there a way to merge all the JSON objects so as to display all together? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When caling `this.setState({data: res.msg});` you set the `data` field to be equal to `res.msg`, thus overriding it.

You want `data` to be an array, and you add an item to it when you receive a message:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    data: []
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
 socket.emit('initialize');
 socket.on('msg', res => {
   this.setState({data: [...this.state.data, res.msg]});
 })
}
```

Also, you probably don't want to print `{Object.keys(this.state.data)}` anymore in the first column  but `{Object.keys(item)}`